# HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout not working?

Tags: android

Android 4.1.2

I write some code for gets json from Internet web-server.

```
    HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, 4000); // 4 sec
    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, 1000); // 1 sec

    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(params);
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
    httpGet.setParams(params);

    try {
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
        StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
        int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
        if (statusCode == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream content = entity.getContent();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(content));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                builder.append(line);
            }
        } else {
            Log.message("Download fail");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // request new address for object
        // creating new object is a faster then setLength(0)
        builder = new StringBuilder();
    }
    return builder.toString();
```

But timeout connection not equ 4 seconds. App is waiting 30 seconds. Where I am mistaken?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout()` is [not working well](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2409). I'm not sure this will help you, but it's a workaround that mostly works:

```
private static final int CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 5000; // Timeout until a connection is established
private static final int SOCKET_TIMEOUT = 5000; // Timeout for waiting for data
private static final long MCC_TIMEOUT = 5000;

HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
setTimeouts(httpGet.getParams());

private static void setTimeouts(HttpParams params) {
  params.setIntParameter(CoreConnectionPNames.CONNECTION_TIMEOUT, CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
  params.setIntParameter(CoreConnectionPNames.SO_TIMEOUT, SOCKET_TIMEOUT);
  params.setLongParameter(ConnManagerPNames.TIMEOUT, MCC_TIMEOUT);
}
```

Comment: Without effect for me.